# How to destroy jquery event in the Handle of the same event

Tags: jquery, events, destroy

I would like destroy a event after the same event is fired.

What is the best solution ?

```
var callback = function(){

    $('#myElement').off('click', callback)

    // do stuff
}

$('#myElement').on('click', callback);
```

I do not like having to specify repeatedly `$('#myElement')` and `callback`.

Comment: You can use `one` from jQuery... http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [namespace based event registration](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) here

```
var callback = function(){

    this.off('click.mycallback')

    // do stuff
}

$('#myElement').on('click.mycallback', callback);
```

Or if you want to handler only once then use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$('#myElement').one('click', callback);
```

Comment: hi everyone... any reason for this being downvoted? did I miss anything